# What is the best way to set up a proxy server for IE8?

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-8

I have a client who is accessing my website through a proxy and is getting different results then the clients we are accessing my site directly.

I want to replicate their system, how can I set up a proxy server locally to replicate their issue?

Comment: At first, can you tell which proxies they use? Is it some script such as [Glype](http://www.glype.com/) or [ASProxy](http://asproxy.sourceforge.net/) or an anonymizer? Or is it a "natural" proxy?